# Python 3 keras: UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated for partly downloaded keras cifar10 dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I need some help to fix my errors. I tried to load the cifar10 dataset and it wasn't able to download completely the first time due to unstable internet, subsequently re-running the code with a stable internet gives this error:

```
UnpicklingError:                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9117078ebdb2> in <module>()
  1 from keras.datasets import cifar10
----> 2 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

c:\users\keboc\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_1.8\lib\site- 
packages\keras\datasets\cifar10.py in load_data(label_mode)
 32 
 33     fpath = os.path.join(path, 'test_batch')
---> 34     x_test, y_test = load_batch(fpath)
 35 
 36     y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (len(y_train), 1))

c:\users\keboc\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_1.8\lib\site-packages\keras\datasets\cifar.py in load_batch(fpath, label_key)
 25             d = cPickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
 26             # decode utf8
---> 27             #d_decoded = {}
 28             for k, v in d.items():
 29                 d_decoded[k.decode('utf8')] = v

UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

I loaded the dataset with the code:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the file `~/.keras/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py.tar.gz` and possibly the folder `~/.keras/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py` if it exists and try again, it should redownload the file, hopefully succeeding this time.

Comment: The file and folder aren't present in that directory. Only the .py files (cifar10.py). So there's nothing to remove.

Comment: @kebochiG Are you sure you are looking in the right place? It sounds like you are looking inside keras' source code, I am talking about the ~/.keras folder, note the . (period) meaning it is a hidden folder in your home folder.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm probably not looking in the right place @Matias.  I am currently looking at 
  "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_1.8\Lib\site-packages\keras\datasets" directory.
Please how can I get to the right place. I also see no hidden folder in my home folder ( where my .ipynb file is) and I have the view hidden folders option ticked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was trying to run my code on a large multi-gpu (like 100 gpus). The issue was that each of my runs where trying to download cifar from scratch, and the download process was running on my CPU instead of my GPUs, so at some point it would be problematic for it download all of them correctly and accurately. Finally, I realized that if I only download the dataset only once and share the folder between all of my experiments, I wouldn't face this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your cifar10 dataset are not downloaded completely ,you should delete the incomplete data and redownload.You can debug the  cifar10.load_data() to see where is your own path().My path is below.Just delete is and redownload.
[this is my path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTmHM.png)
then you can also manually put your downloaded cifar10 data in that path.
  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSuzw.png)